# Add membership start and expire date in contact report

Tags: civimember, civireport

Is there a standard way to add membership start and expire date (filterable) in contact report summary page?

I was trying to get into each row and run custom query to get corresponding data but doesn't work.
I also tried to create a custom field and sync the field with real date but the filter is a problem. And need to set up proper hook to sync data.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using Drupal then if above proves problematic you might find it easier to build as a View.

Comment: My contact summary report in CiviCRM 4.5 works fine and shows membership start and expiry dates. Can you provide more details? One thing that can be confusing is that CiviCRM allows more than one membership per constituent, so there's no one-to-one connection between memberships and contacts, and getting membership data into contact reports is not as obvious as you might expect.